# Category Count and EE transcribe

Tags: channel-entries, categories, transcribe

I’m using a plugin name « Category Count » to count the number of entries in a specific category.

When i create an entry, transcribe create one for French and one for English so my counter show me two entries. I need only one entry count.

Here’s my code :

```
{exp:channel:categories category_id="8" style="linear"}
  {if soin-visage-section == 'Catégorie' }
    <li><a href="{exp:transcribe:uri path="soin-visage/par-categorie/list/{category_url_title}"}">{category_name} ({exp:catcount cat_id="{category_id}" channel="products"})</a></li>
 {/if}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Someone Can help me with this ?

Thank you very much.

Kind regards

Jérôme

Comment: Could you edit your question and use code block markdown please? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

It's possible Transcribe and Category Count aren't very sympatico. How about just running a query with the Query module? This is completely untested as I'm quite busy but I though I'd throw it out their. Probably have a bunch parse order issues with this idea.

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT COUNT(*) as outer_count FROM exp_category_posts WHERE cat_id = '8';"}
    {exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_category_posts WHERE cat_id = '8' LIMIT {outer_count} / 2;"}
        {count}
    {/exp:query}
{/exp:query}
```